# Definition of a group representation

Tags: representation-theory

A representation of a group on a vector space $V$, is a group homomorphism $f: G \to GL(V)$, where $GL(V)$ is the general linear group.  However, Wikipedia defines it as a map $G \times V \to V$ such that the map $V \to V$ defined by $v \to g \cdot v$ is a linear for every $g \in G$, and satisfies $e \cdot v = v$ and $g_1 \cdot(g_2 \cdot v) = (g_1g_2) \cdot v$

My question is why does Wikipedia not require $v \to g \cdot v$ to be a linear isomorphism?  (since $GL(V)$ is the group of invertible linear maps)?

Comment: It follows from the definition. Use the fact that every element in the group has an inverse.

Comment: Oh right,  left and right inverse of the linear map will be given by the map $v \to g^{-1} \cdot v$, so they're isomorphisms.

Comment: Looks good. Write up an answer to the question, so that others can learn from it.